# How to download data files from ENA with greater bandwidth?

Tags: shell, ftp, wget

Hi im trying to download around 4000 Fastq files from ENA ftp server using the following loop command:

```
while read i; do n=$(echo "$i" | sed -E 's/(SRR...).*/\1/'); wget ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/$n/$i/$i*; done  < IDS.txt
```

However I have a 20 mb bandwidth for downloading but when im downloading the downloading speed is between  100–350 kbs only and hence, it is taking ages to download the data. Do anyone have an Idea of aspera? or anything else anyone can help with or recommend?

Comment: You can use `--max-threads` argument to speed up wget, this argument makes wget open multiple connections to the host.

If this kind of speed up is not enough, you can look for command-line download managers.

Comment: I have already tried --max-threads no improvement

Comment: `wget` does not support a `--max-threads` option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible reasons that you are seeing a bandwidth usage lower than your total available bandwidth:

1. Your ISP throttles your bandwidth on a per-connection basis. That is, each HTTP(S) connection has throttled bandwidth. In this case, using multiple threads / processes can be very useful. For this, I would recommend using [GNU Wget2](https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2). Wget2 is the next version of Wget which is written with multi-threading support. It is still in alpha phase, but we deem it pretty ready for public use.
2. The server has a throttled bandwidth. If the server is throttling the total bandwidth, there's nothing you can do to improve your speeds.

Full Disclosure: I am the maintainer of both GNU Wget and GNU Wget2.